# Minecraft the Data Tag Does Not Match

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to detect an item when I throw it, however it says the data tag does not match for `0ece610b-7039-4fa6-beb4-2d876cbcb37a`.

Here is the command:
`>scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] S 1 {Item: id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:8,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"South"}}}}`

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What are the details of the item you have?

Comment: Hmm, variable name "S", you will surely remember what that means in months/years...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an opening bracket for the item compound.
`{Item: id:"m` should be `{Item:{id:"m`

Your damage value is testing for an integer and needs to test for a short so it needs to be followed by an s.
`Damage:8` should be `Damage:8s`

For a final command of:

```
scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] S 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:8s,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"South"}}}}
```

---

Also, just to note it, you can give the item a [scoreboard tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags) which will allow you to target the item without having to create a scoreboard objective.  It will use the same dataTag from above.

Here is the command:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add S {Item:{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:8s,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"South"}}}}
```

To target the item, you can use the [tag argument in the target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_tag) within another command.  An example command to kill the item:

```
/kill @e[tag=S]
```

Answer (score 0):

Damage is a short, so use Damage:8s

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many closing braces, try removing one from the end.